# How do you populate a field if it doesn't exist in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am writing an aggregate for MongoDB, but am running into an issue with making sure a field is always present inside of my `$project` query. I would like to write something like this:

```
{
    'foo': '$foo.bar' || ''
}
```

Which would populate `foo` with `foo.bar` or an empty string if the property is not there. I've tried using `$or`, `$cond`, and `$exists`, but none of them are guaranteeing the presence of `foo`.

Comment: if you want check some filed exists or not use $exists operator, otherwise if you want to check some field has value or not you most check the filed with null, see mongodb docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields

Comment: @Mo5tafa, as I mention in the question, `$exists` is not what I am looking for. I am not merely attempting to check for the presence of a field, but rather wanting to guarantee that that field is present regardless of its presence in the data object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
{
    'foo': {
        $cond: {
            'if': "$foo.bar",
            'then': "$foo.bar",
            'else': ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, $exists operator is best way to check some filed is exists or not:

```
db.collection.find({ 'somefiled' : { '$exists' : true }});
```

You will not get anything when a field does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This will only verify that the field exists, it will not populate the value if it does _not_ exist.